# Can I listen for events from Notepad++ when making plugin

Tags: events, plugins, notepad++

I can't seem to find info on whether or not this is possible, but I want to know if its possible to have a notepad++ plugin listen for events from the notepad++/scintilla application. If so what are those events and where can I find a list of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer, you use the beNotified(...) method that comes with all the plugin templates to "listen" for events/notifications.